# Good image gallery engines

Tags: graphics, image-gallery

What are the best open source image gallery engines? Both stand-alone, and for existing frameworks such as Wordpress or Drupal.

Hopefully we can build a good list here over time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Gallery](http://gallery.menalto.com) is the classic choice.  It has skins, security layers, heaps of plugins, etc, but can be run with the default settings easily if you want to.  I've used it for years.

Answer (score 1):

GOOD QUESTION, lots of people ask this in many web forums so hopefully we will get some good responses to this, and have a good list of solutions.

Personally I always used to say something like Gallery or some other OS script, but recently I have found myself using more and more something like a simple php script which just spits our a  list of images (maybe 7 a page) but relying on a Javascript library such as mootools or Ext to provide all the functionality, particularly for small or individual galleries. Im particularly loving the noobslide mootools class at the moment which has some lovely gallery effects.

[Noobslide](http://www.efectorelativo.net/laboratory/noobSlide/)

I suppose at the end of the day its all down to what you need, there will be no one answer that fits all but a number of different solutions will hopefully show up here that will suit different peoples needs.