# The Definitive Image Gallery Engine / Plugin Guide

Tags: graphics, image-gallery

I want to get a good list of image gallery engines of all flavours: Stand alone, plugins for Wordpress or Rails, AJAX, no AJAX, using simple folders or a database on the server.

Please state what is needed (eg MySQL and Django) to run each item if possible. Thanks!

[I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203193/good-image-gallery-engines) a while back but had limited responses. Hopefully with more users and a small bounty this will pick up more steam. EDIT - can't attach a bounty for two days. Hold tight.]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are the ones I recall at the moment, they are all easy to integrate and they don't require much implementation to use. They all have a good and appealing design. Hope it helps.

- [Cooliris](http://www.cooliris.com/): Runs on flash, uses an
  RSS feed to show the images
- [FancyBox](http://fancy.klade.lv/): Jquery Plugin, you
  just need to have create an < a
  ref... arround the < img src...
- [LightBox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/): jQuery plugin, also
  easy to use.
- [Photo Slider](http://opiefoto.com/articles/photoslider): jQuery plugin, as
  some thumbnails bellow which you can
  use to slide through the images
- [SimpleViewer](http://www.airtightinteractive.com/simpleviewer/): Nice Design, shows
  thumbnails and images
- [HighSlide JS](http://highslide.com/): Javascript viewer

Comment: +1 Great sites.  I use lightbox2 on my personal site, but may have to look at Cooliris and Fancybox a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

I like [Gallery](http://gallery.menalto.com) the best of any I've seen.  It requires PHP and [a database](http://gallery.menalto.com/requirements)).  It can be plugged in to WordPress and [other CMSish things](http://gallery.menalto.com/features)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [SourceForge](http://tinyurl.com/sf-results)

Comment: I get 'no results found' when clicking on that link

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a gallery application I recommend the open source project '[Gallery2](http://gallery.menalto.com/)'.

Answer (score 1):

[Lytebox](http://www.dolem.com/lytebox/) is easy to use and very nice. It's enhanced version of LightBox.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.silverlight-blog.it/ontheroad/photogallery/index.html) is a nice photogallery using silverlight. [Slide.Show](http://www.codeplex.com/SlideShow) is another slick Silverlight gallery. There are many [gallery modules](http://www.snowcovered.com/snowcovered2/Default.aspx?tabid=295&search=gallery) available for [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com), and an official module. There are also a great many available on [Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?ProjectSearchText=gallery).